# string indices must be integers while trying to loop thru JSON

Tags: python, json

This is how my JSON looks like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Sid": "xxx",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxx"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "yyy",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxx/AWSLogs/yyy/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

I want to loop thru Statement array. This is how my loop looks like:

```
for p in policy['Statement']:
   print p
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

`print(type(policy))` yields `<type 'unicode'>`

---

This is how Policy looks like:

```
{
    u'Policy': u'{
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [{
            "Sid": "xxx",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxx"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "yyy",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::yyy/AWSLogs/yyy/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        }]
    }'
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Copy pasted your structure and code, and it's outputting fine. Tested in Python 2 as well, since I noticed your `print` is a statement.

Comment: I assume you used `policy = json.loads(...)`?

Comment: Sounds like you still have a json string. `json.loads` will convert it to a python data structure. The good news is you are techincally right, it is JSON. The bad news is that JSON is a serialization format and needs to be "nativized" to be used.

Comment: Yup. I just replicated the problem. I think your data structure you are showing is actually the *string* representation. You need to actually call `json.loads` on it, and iterate over the result of that. The result of `json.loads` will give you a proper Python data structure you can use.

Comment: Thanks all of you. `json.loads` is what I needed. `for p in json.loads(policy)['Statement']: print p['Action']` is producing the right result